# Does Opencv 3 SVM trainAuto scale labels too?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, opencv3.0

I'm using OpenCV 3.0.0. When running OpenCV's SVM example [1](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/tutorials/ml/introduction_to_svm/introduction_to_svm.html) I noticed that when auto trained instead of trained, the predicted values are between 0 and 1. I don't see the same behavior when I run the same example directly with libsvm.

Is this a bug or an intentional scaling of the labels along with the other features? The behavior also seems to be undocumented.

Here is the code I'm running:

```
    // Set up training data
size_t numberOfSamples = 4;
cv::Mat1i labelsMat(numberOfSamples, 1);
labelsMat(0, 0) = 1;
labelsMat(1, 0) = -1;
labelsMat(2, 0) = -1;
labelsMat(3, 0) = -1;

cv::Mat1f trainingDataMat(numberOfSamples, 2);
// Sample 0
trainingDataMat(0, 0) = 501;
trainingDataMat(0, 1) = 10;

// Sample 1
trainingDataMat(1, 0) = 255;
trainingDataMat(1, 1) = 10;

// Sample 2
trainingDataMat(2, 0) = 501;
trainingDataMat(2, 1) = 255;

// Sample 3
trainingDataMat(3, 0) = 10;
trainingDataMat(3, 1) = 501;

// Set up SVM's parameters
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::SVM> svm = cv::ml::SVM::create();
svm->setType(cv::ml::SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(cv::ml::SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setTermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria(cv::TermCriteria::MAX_ITER, 100, 1e-6));

// Train the SVM with given parameters
cv::Ptr<cv::ml::TrainData> td =
    cv::ml::TrainData::create(trainingDataMat, cv::ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labelsMat);

// train the SVM
// svm->train(td);

// or auto train
svm->trainAuto(td);

// predict
// first point used for training
cv::Mat point1 = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 2) << 501, 10);
float response1 = svm->predict(point1); 
// second point used for training
cv::Mat point2 = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 2) << 255, 10);
float response2 = svm->predict(point2);

std::cout << "first point: " << response1 << "\n" <<
          << "second point: " << response2 << std::endl;
```

If ran with trainAuto it will output 0 and 1 instead of -1 and 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently it was a bug that is fixed now:

http://code.opencv.org/issues/4464

Comment: Yes, it's a bug. Update to OpenCV 3.2 ;)

Comment: I also have this problem in OpenCV 4 with python. Your link doesn't work correctly. please check it.